# Last record number (field is not a primary key)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a table in my `MSAccess` database named "Check_Numbers".

Fields:

- ID (Primary Key)
- Check_Numbers

Check_Numbers field is where the check number that the user should be getting from to be shown in a `TextBox`. That check_number is editable and should be in series. For example my first check has a check_number `0001`, when I open the form to create a new check, `0002` should already be inside the `TextBox` without the user typing the numbers, but he can edit it on the same form if he wishes to.

I've been searching for this, but Google doesn't seem to understand my question or what I'm trying to say, so I decided to ask here instead. I hope someone who knows it can help me.

Comment: Can you just have it inserted as a integer and add 1 to it?

Comment: `Select MAX(Check_Numbers) + 1 From Check_Numbers` for loading the number suggest. Additionally you should check if a number is already taken if the user manually edits it.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do actually, but I can't get the last recorded number under the field `Check_Numbers` . and the user should see the number before saving it. @vbdevelp

Comment: If I do that, does my `check_numbers` field needs to be a primary key? @AlexB.

Comment: I don't think so, you can just have it pick up the other data with the number, but it does not have to be the primary key.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll do that instead. I'll get back to you guys if I was able to make it work. Thanks so much for the help! :) @vbdevelp

Comment: you should not have to, i think i was wrong when i said it does have to be the primary key.

Comment: Of course, I hope this helped you.

Comment: Did it end up working for you @Erica

Comment: That´s why you should execute the statement when you load your form. Btw...this will not work if your table is empty. If so, you must either create one dummy record or check if Max(Check_Numbers) retruns null.

Comment: You are correct, otherwise the program can go crazy, it happened to me before and I had no idea what was wrong then I realized...

Comment: hey @vbdevelp and Alex B.  I am so sorry for the late response, I encountered a problem before trying out your suggestion, but was able to fix it and finally tried what you told me to do and it finally worked the way I wanted it. Thank you to you both. (can't tag 2 users, sorry) but thanks to you two for the help! :)

Comment: too sad i'm not yet allowed to vote up :(